# what is the meaning of this set $\{x : f(x) \neq g(x)\}?$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, lebesgue-measure

Note :My motivation comes from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4205530/why-2-nh-nx-t-nx-except-in-v-n-k-n-rudin-rca-lusins-theorem) question

I have some  confusion regarding Rudin RCA book, page number $55$

> Lusin's  theorem  : Suppose  $f$ is a complex   measurable  function on $X$. $\mu(A) < \infty$ , $f(x)= 0$ if  $x \notin A $ and $\epsilon >0$. Then  there  exists a $g \in C_c(X)$ such that $ \mu(\{x : f(x) \neq g(x)\}) <\epsilon$

**My confusion** : what is the meaning of this set $\{x : f(x) \neq g(x)\}?$

**My thinking** : $\{x : f(x) \neq g(x)\}=\{x : f(x) - g(x) \neq 0 \}=\{x : f(x) - g(x)> 0 \ \text{or} \ f(x) - g(x) <0  \}$

If $f-g >0$  then $\{x : f(x) - g(x) > 0 \}= (f-g)^{-1}(0,\infty)$

If $f-g <0$  then $\{x : f(x) - g(x) < 0 \}= (f-g)^{-1}(-\infty,0)$

But here $\mu(-\infty,0)=\mu(0,\infty)=\infty \implies   \mu(\{x : f(x) \neq g(x)\})=\infty$

This  lead to the contradiction that  $ \mu(\{x : f(x) \neq g(x)\} <\epsilon$

Comment: No. $f$ and $g$ are complex, so $f(x)\ne g(x)$ does **not** say $f(x)>g(x)$ or $f(x)<g(x)$.

Comment: Ok@DavidC.Ullrich but every real  is complex

Comment: @jasmine But not every complex is real.

Comment: actually I was aware that every real is complex. Say $z=1$ and $w=i$. So $z\ne w$. So tell me which of $z<w$ and $z>w$ is true...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I think $z < w$ .I mean, $1 <i$  because $\mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{C}$

Comment: oh dear. the right answer was "of course both $1<i$ and $i<1$ are nonsense - sure enough $z\ne w$ does not imply $z<w$ or $w<z$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Two remarks**

First, you're dealing with complex maps. Hence

$$\{x : f(x) - g(x) \neq 0 \}\neq \{x : f(x) - g(x)> 0 \ \text{or} \ f(x) - g(x) <0  \}$$

Second, if you would deal with real maps, the measure $\mu$ is not performed on $(0,\infty)$ or $(-\infty ,0)$ but on the inverse image of those sets under $f-g$. Which means that

$$\mu(\{x : f(x) \neq g(x)\} = \mu((f-g)^{-1}[(0, \infty)]) + \mu((f-g)^{-1}[(-\infty, 0)]) \lt \epsilon.$$

Comment: can you elaborate more on complex map. I mean , what   is  the  meaning of  $\{x : f(x) \neq g(x)\} $ on the complex map ?

Comment: That is just  $\mu(A) - \mu((f-g)^{-1}[0])$.